# Is $f(x)=x^{2}$ a continuous function defined on the following topological spaces?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

I have the following statement which I need to prove or disprove.
Suppose $f(x)=x^{2}$ from $(\mathbb{R}, \tau_{5}) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R}, \tau_{cofi})$, where $\tau_{5}=${$A\subseteq \mathbb{R}:5\in A$}$\cup$ {$\emptyset$} and $\tau_{cofi}=${$A\subseteq \mathbb{R}:A^{c}$ is a finite set}.
Basically, I know that, in order to prove continuity, I need to take an open set $B \in Y$ and see if its inverse image is an open set.
But how do I calculate the inverse image?
For example, if $B=\mathbb{R}-${1}, what is the inverse image of that set?

Answer (score 2):

Let $A=\mathbb R \setminus {\{25\}}$. Then $f^{-1}(A)=\mathbb R \setminus \{5,-5\}$ which is not open.

Comment: Thanks. Know I got it. 